# How many parameters can be passed to UI-SREF of angularjs 1.6

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on angularjs1.6 and i have passed 13 parameters through UI-SREF.
For eg:-
a data-ui-sref="editcomplaint({pcustomername:'{{t.CustomerName|uppercase}}',pcompanyname:'{{t.CompanyName}}',pproductsbought:'{{t.ProductsBought}}',pnoofqty:'{{t.Noofqty}}',pdateofpurchase:'{{t.DateofPurchase}}',pcostpaid:'{{t.CostPaid}}',paddress:'{{t.Address}}',punit:'{{t.Unit}}',plocation:'{{t.Location}}', preason:'{{t.reason}}',pcomplaintno:'{{t.complaintno}}',peditcomplaint:'{{1}}',pcomplainttype:'{{t.ComplaintType}}'})"OPEN(when i click this open link, the above parameters are passed.)

Then i capture this parameters in Config file like this
 .state('editcomplaint',{
             url: '/editcomplaint/?pcustomername?pcompanyname?pproductsbought?pnoofqty?pdateofpurchase?pcostpaid?paddress?punit?plocation?preason?pcomplaintno?peditcomplaint?pcomplainttype',

but when i saw in the output it displays only 10 parameters.

in output screen,
http://localhost:6492/App/Login/Index.html#!/editcomplaint/?pcustomername=SDFSDF&pcompanyname=dsfds&pproductsbought=sdfds&pnoofqty=12&pdateofpurchase=2018-05-04T00:00:00&pcostpaid=22&punit=21&plocation=fdfdfd&peditcomplaint=1&pcomplainttype=Incorrect%20description%20of%20product

In the above output i am not able to see preason and pcomplaintno parameters.

How to solve this?

Comment: you can not link to your localhost to show the output...

Comment: It is working for 10 parameters.Is there any parameter restriction in ui-sref.